# How can I bind the model to the view?

Tags: backbone.js

When the view is initialized, how can I bind the model to the specific View that is created? The view is current initialized at the start of the application. Also, how can I bind the model to the collection?
(function ($) { //loads at the dom everything

```
//Creation, Edit, Deletion, Date
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        text: "write here...",
        done: false
    },

    initialize: function (){
        if(!this.get("text")){
            this.set({"text": this.default.text});
        }
    },

    edit: function (){
        this.save({done: !this.get("done")});
    },

    clear: function (){
        this.destroy();
    }
});

var NoteList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Note
});

var NoteView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    el: "body",

    initialize: function(){
        alert("initialized");
        var list = new NoteList;    
        return list;
    },

    events: {
        "click #lol" : "createNote"
    },

    createNote : function(){
        var note = new Note;
        this.push(note);
        alert("noted");
    }
});

var ninja = new NoteView;
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I just took a look at @James Woodruff's answer, and that prompted me to take another look at your code. I didn't look closely enough the first time, but I'm still not sure what you're asking. If you're asking how to have a model or view listen for and handle events triggered on the other, then check out James's example of calling `bind()` to have the view listen for `change` (or `change:attr`) events on the model (although I'd recommend using `on()` instead of `bind()`, depending what version of Backbone you're using).

But based on looking at your code again, I've revised my answer, because I see some things you're trying to do in ways that don't make sense, so maybe that's what you're asking about.

## New Answer

Here's the code from your question, with comments added by me:

```
var NoteView = Backbone.View.extend ({

    // JMM: This doesn't make sense. You wouldn't normally pass `el`
    // to extend(). I think what you really mean here is
    // passing el : $( "body" )[0] to your constructor when you
    // instantiate the view, as there can only be one BODY element.

    el: "body",

    initialize: function(){
        alert("initialized");

        // JMM: the next 2 lines of code won't accomplish anything.
        // Your NoteList object will just disappear into thin air.
        // Probably what you want is one of the following:
        // this.collection = new NoteList;
        // this.list = new NoteList;
        // this.options.list = new NoteList;

        var list = new NoteList;    

        // Returning something from initialize() won't normally
        // have any effect.        

        return list;
    },

    events: {
        "click #lol" : "createNote"
    },

    createNote : function(){
        var note = new Note;

        // JMM: the way you have your code setup, `this` will be
        // your view object when createNote() is called. Depending
        // what variable you store the NoteList object in (see above),
        // you want something here like:
        // this.collection.push( note ).

        this.push(note);
        alert("noted");
    }
});
```

Here is a revised version of your code incorporating changes to the things I commented on:

```
var NoteView = Backbone.View.extend( {

  initialize : function () {

    this.collection = new NoteList;    

  },
  // initialize


  events : {

    "click #lol" : "createNote"

  },
  // events


  createNote : function () {

    this.collection.push( new Note );

    // Or, because you've set the `model` property of your
    // collection class, you can just pass in attrs.

    this.collection.push( {} );

  }
  // createNote

} );


var note = new NoteView( { el : $( "body" )[0] } );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still definitely don't understand backbone enough to be able to use it. I initially thought I could just try and learn as I go but it seems the best way to learn to use it would be to look at the source code. That being said, I think my initial intentions was to create a view that will be able to create new models and insert them into the collection.

Comment: @Sean you can learn to use it as you go along, but in addition to looking at the docs, looking at the source code is invaluable, since the docs aren't very complete, well laid out, or accurate. If the other answer is more to your point, ok.  But if that's your intention, I'm baffled why you selected the other answer -- it doesn't show that at all. My answer shows a modified version of your code that accomplishes that.

Comment: oh. It wasn't that I thought the other answer was more accurate or than the other, it was just my human error to forget to give you credit. Credits go to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind views to models so when a model updates [triggers an event], all of the corresponding views that are bound to the model update as well. A collection is a container for like models... for example: `Comments Collection` holds models of type `Comment`.

In order to bind a view to a model they both have to be instantiated. Example:

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
       text: "write here..."
    },

    initialize: function(){

    },

    // More code here...

});


var NoteView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
       // Listen for a change in the model's text attribute
       // and render the change in the DOM.
       this.model.bind("change:text", this.render, this);
    },


    render: function(){
       // Render the note in the DOM
       // This is called anytime a 'Change' event
       // from the model is fired.
       return this;
    },

    // More code here...

});
```

Now comes the Collection.

```
var NoteList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Note,

    // More code here...

});
```

Now it is time to instantiate everything.

```
var Collection_NoteList = new NoteList();
var Model_Note = new Note();
var View_Note = new NoteView({el: $("Some Element"), model: Model_Note});

// Now add the model to the collection
Collection_NoteList.add(Model_Note);
```

I hope this answers your question(s) and or leads you in the right direction.